# Document library included on page, wrong language in context menu

Tags: library, modern-pages, language, sitepages, libraries

I added the webpart "Document Library" to a page and made my settings, I deactivated the command bar, selected a library (the page library where the modern pages and news pages are stored by default) and saved the page. When I now look at the page and open the context menu in the library, I can see that it is in English.

[image: englisch context menu]

However, I have set my page to German in the website settings. How can that be? How can I fix this?

Comment: From where you set the language to German in SharePoint Online??

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your issue by changing language settings for my SharePoint site. Maybe it is a SharePoint issue/limitation that after adding a library on a page, it shows the document menu in English only.

As a solution to this, I changed my browser language to German (same language as site) and then I could see the menu **in German and NOT ENGLISH**. Here's the screenshot of the same.

[image]

This is not a SharePoint solution but this is the only thing that worked out for me.

Comment: I tried Chrome, Firefox and InternetExplorer in german language, it did not work. I have switched the command bar on and off, the context menu and the bar were always in English.

Comment: Chrome will give you an option to translate. This option will be there at the end of the address bar. Just click on translate. The site will get refreshed.

Comment: On your screenshot I can see that the command bar is in English?!

Comment: only 1 selected is in English. The screenshot was taken when only browser language was changed to german and site language was english

Comment: Also, looking at a document library in german directly, your context-menu seems to be automatically translated by the browser, because SharePoint actually uses "Öffnen" instead of "Öffnen Sie" und "Oben anheften" instead of "Oben anpinnen" - at least in my instance (target first release, so this might have been changed).